# Conflict of version between System.Text.Json and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe when using JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, .net

Our C# application is using .Net Framework 4.7.2 and we're trying to implement JsonSerializer in System.Text.Json. We are able to build the solution without any issues but when we try to run the application we get the following error

> Resolve failed: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
> Caught exception while running: Main
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> File name: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> at System.Span`1..ctor(T[] array)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at Project.Class1.Main(String[] args) in D:\Project\Class1.cs:line 36

Looking at the version of System.Rutime.CompilerServices.Unsafe that is installed in NuGet, it's 5.0.0 and inside our app.config file, we have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now, since 4.0.4.1 is within the range of the oldVersion, I would assume that it should be redirecting to 5.0.0.0 instead of looking for 4.0.4.1, but I must be mistaken. I also tried to change the oldVersion to "4.0.4.1" but that did not help.

If I try to change the version of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe to the package version 4.5.3, which corresponds to version 4.0.4.1, then System.Text.Json needs to downgraded from 5.0.2 to 2.0.0.11. This version does not contain JsonSerializer so it won't work with our application.

Is there a way that we could successfully redirect from looking for the old version (4.0.4.1) to looking for the latest version that is installed (5.0.0.0)? Any feedback or suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: Could you possibly upgrade your project to .NET 5?

Comment: I don’t know for the original author, but I can’t, because I’m writing an extension and I need to support at lease VS2019 (maybe older).

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem and found the following solution/workaround.

In regular .NET Framework applications (exe or web applications), configuring assembly binding redirects in the app/web.config file fixed the problem for us. However, we also use System.Text.Json in situations where this is not an option, for example, in .NET Framework libraries invoked via COM.

In those cases, we use the following code to redirect all requests to the 4.* version of the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe library to the 6.* version:

```
internal class BindingRedirector
{
    private static bool _systemTextJsonProblemFixed = false;

    public static void FixSystemTextJsonProblem()
    {
        if (_systemTextJsonProblemFixed)
        {
            return;
        }

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += WorkaroundAssemblyResolver;
        JsonSerializer.Serialize("dummyText");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= WorkaroundAssemblyResolver;

        _systemTextJsonProblemFixed = true;
    }

    private static Assembly? WorkaroundAssemblyResolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        if (name.Name == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" && name.Version.Major == 4)
        {
            // Return (already loaded) version 6.0 instead.
            var ass = typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Assembly;
            if (ass.GetName().Version.Major == 6)
            {
                return ass;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Just make sure you invoke `BindingRedirector.FixSystemTextJsonProblem()` before doing any System.Text.Json operations, for example, by calling it during application startup or by calling it in the static constructor of classes using System.Text.Json.